# How to search links within iframe using php

Tags: php, search, iframe

I have placed an iframe on my webpage that is located on external server. it comtains multiple hyperlinks. I want to capture those links and display them on my own webpage. i.e. those links appear to be part of my webpage.
How can i search links that are displayed within that iframe using php.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you know the iframe source url.

You can load the file in php using:

```
$content=file_get_contents($url);
```

and analyse the content aftewards.

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: when the iframe loads , it gnerates some url dynamically depending of the username who is logged on to my website. Its a sort of add on  for my website.

Comment: I see... in this case what you need to do is screen scraping using javascript. but you cannot do that only with php and without an url.

Comment: when webpage loads, if i see the iframe source, i can see all the links randomly generated. just want to capture those,and place them outside iframe. without modifying any thing.